# How to implement swipeable segments in ionic 3?

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, ionic3

I have to implement swipeable segments in ionic 3 application.

I am using **https://github.com/siddhartha-gupta/ionic-3-swipe-able-segments/tree/develop/src/pages** directives but i am getting following error:

```
<ion-content padding>
 <div [ngSwitch]="category" swipeSegment [tabsList]="categories" 
[ERROR ->][(currentTab)]="category" 
 (tabChanged)="onTabChanged($event)" class="swipe-area">
 <ion-list *ngSw"): 
ng:///InvitefriendPageModule/InvitefriendPage.html@60:66
Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'tabsList' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("

<ion-content padding>
 <div [ngSwitch]="category" swipeSegment [ERROR ->] . 
[tabsList]="categories" [(currentTab)]="category" 
(tabChanged)="onTabChanged($event)" class="swipe-ar"): 
ng:///InvitefriendPageModule/InvitefriendPage.html@60:42
Can't bind to 'currentTab' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. 
("
```

My code is:

In app.module.ts:

```
import { SwipeSegmentDirective } from '../directives/swipe- segment.directive';

@NgModule({
 declarations: [
  MyApp,
  SwipeSegmentDirective
  // ProgressBarComponent
],
```

In invitefriend.ts:

```
export class InvitefriendPage {

public category: string = 'everyone';
public categories: Array<string> = ['everyone', 'group', 'contact', 
'directory']

// tab1Root: any = "EveryonePage";
// tab2Root: any = "GroupPage";
// tab3Root: any = "ContactPage";
// tab4Root: any = "DirectoryPage";
// public categories: Array<string> = ['everyone', 'group', 'contact', 
'directory']

 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: 
  NavParams) {
 }

 ionViewDidLoad() {
  console.log('ionViewDidLoad InvitefriendPage');
 }

 onTabChanged(tabName) {
  this.category = tabName;
 }
```

In invitefriend.html:

```
<ion-header>
 <ion-navbar color="danger">   

    <ion-toolbar class="toolbar-color myToolbar">
     <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="category" class="tabsSeg">

      <ion-segment-button value="everyone" class="segBtn tabname 
        active activated">
         Everyone
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="group" class="segBtn tabname">
        Group
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="contact" class="segBtn tabname">
        Contact
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="directory" class="segBtn tabname">
        Directory
      </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
   </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-navbar>

 </ion-header> 


<ion-content padding>
 <div [ngSwitch]="category" swipeSegment [tabsList]="categories" 
  [(currentTab)]="category" (tabChanged)="onTabChanged($event)" 
   class="swipe-area">
  <ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'everyone'">
   <ion-item>
    Batman Begins
   </ion-item>
   <ion-item>
    Transporter
   </ion-item>
   <ion-item>
    Million Dollar Baby
   </ion-item>
 </ion-list>

 <ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'group'">
  <ion-item>
    Game of Thrones
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    Daredevil
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    Arrow
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>

<ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'contact'">
  <ion-item>
    Ice Age
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    Lion King
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    Up
  </ion-item>
 </ion-list>

 <ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'directory'">
   <ion-item>
    Ice Age1
   </ion-item>
   <ion-item>
    Lion King1
   </ion-item>
   <ion-item>
    Up1
   </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
 </div>
</ion-content>
```

I need any solution to solve above error, please give here solution as soon as possible, it would be really appreciated.

Comment: is the page lazy loaded?

Comment: yes @Suraj Rao, it is lazy loaded

Comment: try setting the directive in the declarations in the page module instead of app module

Comment: thanks a lot @Suraj Rao. it is solved by your helpful suggestion.